# Error when connecting unidac 4.0.1 with sqlite database

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-xe, devart, unidac

I'm delphi user, i got problem when try to connect sqlite with my unidac 4.0.1 component. 
I've dropped  `TUniConnection`, Sqlite uniprovider, setting client library at specification property, but it always raised an error:

> file is encrypted or is not database.

I've used 
- lastest sqlite3.dll 
- delphi xe
- unidac 4.0.1
- sqlite2009 Pro Enterprise (for creating sqlite 3 database file)

Thanks.

Comment: Latest version is vague, providing the exact version is more helpfull for people willing to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did encrypt the file using Sqlite2009 Pro Enterprise.

The standard `sqlite3.dll` does not implement encryption.

You'll need either the [SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE)](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html), either another implementation (like [the one embedded in wxcode](http://wxcode.sf.net/)).

If your file is not encrypted, try to use another SQLite3 viewer (like [SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index) or our [SynDBExplorer](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/07/22/SynDBSQLite3%3A-SQLite3-direct-access)) to guess if the file is correct.

Also ensure the file is not created in "C:\Program Files" folder, which is made "virtual" by the UAC.